# When does order of partial derivatives matter?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I've taken multivariate calculus and am wondering if I can see a specific function where the order of taking the partial derivative matters. I've been told that there are some exceptions where $ \dfrac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} \ne \dfrac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial y \partial x} $, so I'm curious to see what this looks like.

EDIT:
And why would this true?

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives#Requirement_of_continuity)

Comment: I don't accept this example because it seems to be purely an artifact of whomever created this graph. It would be exactly the same to just represent this in polar coordinates with $ z=r^2 \sin \theta \cos \theta ( \cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta)$ and the problem doesn't come up and the order doesn't matter again.  @Zircht

Comment: $\frac{d^2 z}{drd\theta}$ is not the same as $\frac{d^2 z}{dxdy}$! The problem is still present in the polar-coordinate-form, though hidden. You can almost always change coordinates to make the problem 'go away' so I guess you will not accept any examples.

Comment: How? If we evaluate the derivative at a point we get a consistent answer, the slope is always zero at the origin which matches exactly what I see when I look at it. I don't see why using rectangular coordinates to represent the origin will somehow change the derivative at a point since it is purely a perspective... It is some kind of artifact of dividing by zero being undefined and then when you choose to define it, it is somehow chosen incorrectly. @Winther

Comment: Try calculating $\frac{d^2z}{dxdy}$ and $\frac{d^2z}{dydx}$ from the polar-coordinate form and see what you get. Again $\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{d^2z}{drd\theta}$ is not the same as $\lim_{(x,y)\to 0}\frac{d^2z}{dxdy}$. btw there are no 'nice' examples, since all 'nice' (smooth) functions have the interchanging property.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I guess when I think of "the derivative" I imagine the shape of it at that point as something completely independent of coordinate system. It seems as though I was tricked into thinking there was some real interesting exception but really all it means when it says they are not equal is that the standard $\textit algorithm$ for computing the derivative is wrong and gives inconsistent results. Oh well.

Comment: @Kainui: No, that's not at all what is meant! It has nothing to do with algorithms. What it means is simply that the number $f''_{xy}(0,0)$ (which has a perfectly nonambiguous definition) is not the same as the number $f''_{yx}(0,0)$ (for this particular function).

Comment: @HansLundmark So why is this the case? I don't see how this would be true, or for that matter even could be true. The shape of the thing is the shape of the thing, how could I go about expressing this same inconsistency with polar coordinates? It seems to me that either the problem is there or it's not there not matter how one looks at it, right?

Comment: The polar coordinate system itself has a singularity at the origin ($\theta$ is undefined there), so you have to be very cautious. What you can tell from the expression $r^2 \sin \theta \cos \theta ( \cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta)$ is that the limit of the function at the origin is zero, but not much more. With some experience, you might in fact suspect that there may be trouble with the second derivatives at the origin, since (roughly speaking) differentiating twice "kills $r^2$" and leaves something that's undefined. But to investigate this, you need to go back to the $(x,y)$ coordinates.

Answer (score 8):

Consider the function $f(x,y):=\frac{xy^3}{x^2+y^2}$, with the additional constraint that $f(0,0):=(0,0)$ -- you can check that this function is continuous and differentiable for all $(x,y)$, from the quotient rule we have $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)=\frac{3xy^2}{x^2+y^2}-\frac{2xy^4}{(x^2+y^2)^2},$$ and at $y=0$ we have $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,0)=0,$ thus $$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}(0,0)=0.\tag1$$ On the other hand, by the quotient rule again $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=\frac{y^3}{x^2+y^2}-\frac{2x^2y^3}{(x^2+y^2)^2},$$ and hence $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,y)=y$. Thus $$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}(0,0)=1.\tag2$$ So you can see from $(1)$ and $(2)$ that $\frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} \neq \frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}$.

Comment: Instead of using rectangular coordinates, if we represent the same graph as $f(r, \theta) = r^2 \sin \theta \cos ^3 \theta$ then the problem goes away completely. It seems like the problem is completely artificial from how you decided the choose your representation of it? @Hakim

Comment: @Kainui See Winther's comment.

Comment: It's just an arbitrary perspective, not a property of the graph. Clearly the derivative is 0 at the origin. This is just an artifact created by a poor notation. @Hakim